# Calling qgis2leaf outside QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis2leaf

I am a computer programmer starting with PyqGis-Python, and I’d need to automate the creation of a webmap using the plugin of qgis2leaf from a QGIS Project. I have reached to call “import qgis2leaf.qgis2leaf_exec” from PYQGIS, but I’d like to call it from outside the QGIS environment.

I am using Pycharm IDE, but it has been impossible to import and call “qgis2leaf.qgis2leaf_exec”.

Do you have any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible as qgis2leaf.qgis2leaf_exec works on a layer list from QGIS and the current map display settings.